# Bind ItemsSource from SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my data structure:

```
public class Movie : IMovie
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<IActor> Actors { get; set; }
}

public class Actor : IActor
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my viewModel:

```
public class MovieViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<IMovie> Movies { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<IMovie>();

        public MovieViewModel()
        {
            foreach (var movie in blc.GetAllMovies())
                Movies.Add(movie);
        }
    }
```

In my `MainWindow` I'am adding `dataContext` by this:

```
this.DataContext = new MovieViewModel();
```

I have 2 listboxes. When I select a movie in first listbox I want to display all actors in second listbox.

I managed to display movies. For some reason actors arent displayed when clicking on any movie.

```
<ListBox x:Name="moviesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMovie, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<ListBox x:Name="actorsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMovie.Actors}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActor, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

What's wrong there?

Comment: How is `SelectedMovie.Cast` defined?

Comment: @LewsTherin sorry, there should be `Actors`. Its typo when I was copying this to `so`.

Comment: Completely unsure, but just by similarity with WinForms, is ther `SelectedValue = {}` attribute available? If so, may be worth to try?

Comment: Is `SelectedMovie` a property of class MovieViewModel, and does it fire a property change notification?

Comment: Can you confirm that the Actors list is populated? Your code might be fine but with no data! Also have you got a datatemplate for actors? Why do you need names in your listboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown where/how SelectedMovie is defined (how it exists in its viewmodel), but

1. The viewmodel in which SelectedMovie is contained (presumably DataContext of the form/page containing the ListBox controls) must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (the MVVM Light ViewModelBase does this for you)
2. The SelectedMovie property must raise the PropertyChanged event in its setter. If you are using MVVM Light, ViewModelBase provides a Set method to do this for you.

Example (using MVVM Light; note I've omitted a lot of details to focus on the core issue):

```
<Window 
    DataContext={Binding MyViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}
    >
    <ListBox x:Name="moviesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMovie, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <ListBox x:Name="actorsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMovie.Actors}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActor, Mode=TwoWay}" /> 
</Window>

public MovieViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<IMovie> Movies { get; } = new ObservableCollection<IMovie>();

    public MovieViewModel()
    {
        foreach (var movie in blc.GetAllMovies())
            Movies.Add(movie);
    }

    private Movie _selectedMovie;
    public Movie SelectedMovie
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedValue;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _selectedValue, value);
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModelLocator
{
    // Constructor to register ViewModels, etc...
    //


    public MovieViewModel MyViewModel => /* resolve the view model */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `SelectedMovie` property in your `MovieViewModel`. You should add one and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever it's set as suggested by @C Robinson, or you could bind directly to the `SelectedItem` property of the `moviesListBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="actorsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Actors, ElementName=actorsListBox}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActor, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `SelectedActor` property in your `ViewModel`.

ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<IMovie> Movies { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<IMovie>();

private IMovie _selectedMovie
public IMovie SelectedMovie
{
   get => _selectedMovie;
   set
   {
      _selectedMovie = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedMovie));
   }
}
```

So when you will select a movie, SelectedMovie setter will be called. There it will raise property changed event for SelectedMovie, and then UI will update the second list.